# Upgrade postgres without messing with ports?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

The [standard procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/pgupgrade.html) for upgrading Postgres appears to require that I temporarily run both the old and the new version. This means that I have to change the port of the old version.

This seems completely unnecessary, given how I’m telling `pg_upgrade` exactly where to find the data directories and it could just go and read all the data directly.

Is this really the only way to upgrade (apart from dump/restore), or am I misunderstanding something? Can I not just ask the upgrader to convert all the binary data files directly, without messing with users, passwords and ports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given step 9 in the link you provided:

> 9.Run pg_upgrade ... Obviously, no one should be accessing the clusters during the upgrade. pg_upgrade  defaults to running servers
>   on port 50432 (sic) to avoid unintended client connections.  You can
>   use the same port numbers for both clusters because the old and new
>   clusters will not be running at the same time. ...

It looks like it is just an available option.